# changing the image on jquery success function?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have this jquery voting script, everything is working fine, it just that the image at the success function of the ajax request is not changing the image?

jquery:

```
$("a.vote_down").click(function(){
    //get the id
    the_id = $(this).attr('id');



    //the main ajax request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_down&id="+$(this).attr("id"),
            url: "votes.php",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeOut();
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).html(msg);
                $("span#votes_count"+the_id).fadeIn();
                            // this is my problem here
                $("span#vote_buttons"+the_id).attr("src", "images/downvoteActive.png");

            }
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<span class='vote_buttons' id='vote_buttons<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>
        <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Vote Up!</a>

        <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_down' id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>Vote Down!</a>
```

css:

```
a.vote_up, a.vote_down {
    display:inline-block;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:center;
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    margin-left:4px;
    text-indent:-900%;
}

a.vote_up {
    background:url("images/upvote.png");
}

a.vote_down {
    background:url("images/downvote.png");
}

        </span>
```

Comment: i think its better for me to rewrite the whole html and css because its not complenting jquery well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Further to the updated question, `span` elements don't have a `src` attribute.

You also have another major issue. You are assigning the same `id` to more than one element: This is happening for the `vote_up` and `vote_down` links.

From what I am understanding, you may want to simply assign a unique `id` to each `vote_up` and `vote_down` link, and them simply change their background url within the success callback.

---

**2nd UPDATE:**

Let's assign a unique id to each `vote_up` and `vote_down` link:

```
<a ... class='vote_up' id='vote_up<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'> ...
<a ... class='vote_down' id='vote_down<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'> ...
```

Then you can try to replace the problematic `attr()` call with this:

```
$("#vote_up" + the_id).css("background-image", "url(images/downvoteActive.png)");
```

---

**Previous Answer:**

You're trying to change the `src` attribute of a `span` element. I guess that should be an `img`, but you can leave out the tag name from the selector:

```
$("#vote_buttons"+the_id).attr("src", "images/downvoteActive.png");
```

Comment: im sorry im a jquery newbie, i dnt understand what you just said

Comment: @gateway: Updated my answer with some further info :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector says "span#vote_buttons", not "img#vote_buttons".  Selectors based on "id" values don't need the tag name, and usually it's a good idea to leave that off.